# Why does the csExWB2 Pass the Wrong User Agent for IE8

Tags: browser, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I am using the [csExWB2 web browser control](http://code.google.com/p/csexwb2) with IE8, and I am noticing it is sending the wrong user agent. It send the MSIE 7.0 in the user agent.

While I know how fix this for each request issued by the control, I am concerned if there is something bigger happening behind the scenes with it - causing it to think it is IE7 .

It seems like the project is not active anymore, and no one has answered this question on their group.

http://groups.google.com/group/csexwb/browse_thread/thread/5868cdeea9e63356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this blogpost http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx

Via a registry setting you can force the control to run in a specific mode.